# Authenticating across multiple applications

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am building 2 express applications and I'm trying to get SSO authentication across both applications.  Essentially, I'm looking for a way to forward the session on to the back end system.

```
Person A logs into the front end application
Person A makes a request to the front end system
Front end system makes a service (REST) call to the back end system
Back end system determines if person A has the correct role to make the request
Back end system makes or denies the request
```

Here is what I'm thinking:

2 sailsJS applications.  One that handles the front end & authentication, and one that handles the back end permission based access to the database.

I'm thinking using sails-permissions for the back end application, and either sails-permissions or sails-auth for the front end.  Both are wrappers for passport.js.

The long way of doing this (and I'm not convinced the right way, as it requires redirecting to the backend system) is to use some kind of SSO (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-sso)

What I would prefer doing is forwarding the session with the request.  Something like

```
    var putArgs = {
        data: myData,
        headers: {"session": req.session}
    }

    client.put("http://localhost:81/myServiceEndpoint", putArgs, function(data, response){
        //Do something with response
    })
```

I do plan on using redis for a session cache, so is there is a way for both applications to use the same redis instance and pass along the key for the session?

NOTES:

When done correctly, the user won't have any interaction with the back end system.  The front end system will make the request to the backend system on behalf of the user.

In order for sails-permissions to work, the user must be fully authenticated.  Just passing the _id of the user and doing a lookup will not work.

Answer (score 0):

How I've accomplished this is to have one central SailsJS REST API, which when provided with valid user credentials, returns an authentication token.

We currently have two front-ends (one SailsJS, one EmberJS), which store this token as a localStorage key with the same name (e.g. my-site-token). Then if either front-end see this in localStorage, they supply it with any REST requests, hey presto, SSO. Without having to store sessions anywhere. The token is in effect the session.

Comment: How do you pass the token? Also how does the central API know what to do with the token to link it to the session?

Comment: The token is supplied as a header parameter with the REST request. The token is a JSON web token (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), which contains a user object, signed with a private token.

To the front-end, it's an unreadable string of alphanumeric characters, the JSON web token module converts this into information about the user, in the back end. In your case, your sessions could have a UUID, which is passed inside the token.